# Fazer clicks para gráfico online interativo

Tags: vba, excel-vba, web-crawler, crawling

Preciso fazer a selecionar as informações do lado esquerdo do gráfico de acordo com minha necessidade, mas não consigo referenciar as informações. Não coloquei nenhum código porque tentei de várias formas (de acordo com o que aprendi com minhas outras perguntas) e não tive nenhum sucesso. Segue o link.

http://www.ons.org.br/Paginas/resultados-da-operacao/historico-da-operacao/cmo.aspx

Gostaria de ter pelo menos uma referência de como mudar o período, por exemplo.

Comment: Tente fazer por este site: [https://tableau.ons.org.br/t/ONS_Publico/views/CustoMarginalOperacionalCMO/PainelCustoMarginalOperaoCMO-MdioSemanal?:embed=y&:showAppBanner=false&:showShareOptions=true&:display_count=no&:showVizHome=no](https://tableau.ons.org.br/t/ONS_Publico/views/CustoMarginalOperacionalCMO/PainelCustoMarginalOperaoCMO-MdioSemanal?:embed=y&:showAppBanner=false&:showShareOptions=true&:display_count=no&:showVizHome=no)

Comment: Já tentei também. Não consegui fazer

Comment: Recebi o seguinte Erro: `Erro inesperado

Ocorreu um erro inesperado. Se você continuar recebendo esse erro, contate o administrador do Tableau Server

ID da sessão372A214630CA4B6BA62EBA8FB96B37FC-0:0

Chamada inesperada para acesso à propriedade ou método. .` O site deve possuir alguma proteção que impede alterar estes valores.

Comment: Acesse a caixa de texto com `Set doc = IE.document.getElementbyID("typein_[Parameters].[Parâmetro 5]").getelementsbytagname("span")(0).getelementsbyclassname("QueryBox")(0)` e altere o valor com `doc.Value = "01/01/2018"` Que este erro ocorre. P.S.: o VBA não é das melhores linguagens para Web.

Comment: Ou você pode ir clicando e fazer tudo passo a passo com `doc.Click`

Comment: Pelo menos por enquanto não vou mais trabalhar com VBA. Muito obrigado pela ajuda e pelo seu tempo Daniel. Consegui aprender bastante pelas suas respostas.